# Writing and testing a Javascript library using ES6+ without a browser

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to Webpack and ES6+. I'm trying to write a Javascript library that has some features that require a browser (writing DOM elements, etc.) but most of them are mathematical functions that can be used and tested without a browser. Likewise, I want to be able to test non-UI related features without a browser and UI features with a browser.

I have the following configuration.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "<NAME>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "<DESC>",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "webpack --colors --progress --watch"
  },
  "author": "<ME>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mathjs": "^3.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import math from 'mathjs';

// just a dummy example, uses mathjs.org
function concat(A, B) {
    return math.concat(A, B)
}

export default concat
```

**test/test.js**

```
import assert from 'assert';
import concat from '../index';

describe('Concat', function() {
  describe('#concat()', function() {
    it('should return a horizontal concatenation of two matrices', function() {
      const A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
      const B = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

      const AB = concat(A, B);

      assert.deepEqual(AB, [[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8]]);
    });
  });
});
```

So as of now, I don't really have a way of running `test/test.js` .. how can I add this to my web pack config? Also, is there such thing as "watching" tests? If I wanted to do some tests in the browser, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use some javascript testing framework like [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), for automated tests in browser try [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) or similar projects

Comment: @riyaz-ali I am already using Mocha, my question was more how to use it with Webpack

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part, if you want to use Mocha with webpack then you could use something like [mocha-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-webpack)